# swipe css transition sluggish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, css

I am trying to build a swipe menu for the ipad where a swipe will result in the content from the next menupoint will push the current content out.

However, with barely no content (or just images in divs) it's very fluent. But as soon as I introduce a more compliated DOM it's sluggish in chrome with touch enabled, and unusable on the ipad3 and ipad2.

I've used the transform: translate3d to enabled hardware acceleration, but it just doesn't seem to cut it. Are there any other way to improve performance. I've seen some websites that presents quite a lot of content with a very fluid swipe animation (eg. [The Mobile Playbook](http://www.themobileplaybook.com)), but I can't get that same feel.

I've used the [jquery.event.swipe](http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/) plugin to introduce a code in this format :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var $swipeArea = $("#swipeBox"),
        $pages = $swipeArea.find(".page"),
        $currentPage = $(".currentPage"),
        index = $pages.index($currentPage),
        width = $swipeArea.width();

    $swipeArea
    .on('swipeleft', function(e){
        if(index == $pages.length - 1 ) { return; }
        $pages.eq(index+1).trigger('switchPage');
    })
    .on('swiperight', function(e){
        if(index == 0) { return; }
        $pages.eq(index-1).trigger('switchPage');
    })
    .on('switchPage', function(e){
        $pages.eq(index).removeClass("currentPage");
        $(e.target).addClass("currentPage");
        index = $pages.index($(e.target))
    });
```

Using this css:

```
.swipeContentArea .page{
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   position:absolute;
   left:-100%;
   height:100%;
   z-index:1;
   overflow-x:hidden;
} 
.swipeContentArea .page.currentPage{
   left:0;
   z-index:2;
}
.swipeContentArea .page.currentPage ~ .page {
   left:100%;
}
```

with

```
  transition-property: left,height;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
```

on the swipeArea for the css transitions.

Comment: just a quick comment, the transition-property and duration is of course in -webkit, -moz and the likes. I just pasted in less for less messy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but setting a `left` (and animating it) differs entirely from `translate3d`: `left` is not hardware accelerated, while `translate3d` *is*. Which is probably why it is not running smoothly.

`translate3d` requires parameters in `x`, `y` and `z` form. `x` being the horizontal axis, `y` the vertical and `z` the 'depth' axis, if you will. I ran in to a similar case a while ago and created a simple jquery function that would calculate the width of my sliding element (in your case; the next page), and set a `translate3d` style with either a negative (element moves left) or positive (element moves right) value for `x` on that element.

Say your sliding element is 1200px wide, you would animate it by setting its style like this:

1. the element is the next page: `translate3d(1200px,0px,0px)`
2. the element is the current page: `translate3d(0px,0px,0px)`
3. the element is the previous page: `translate3d(-1200px,0px,0px)`

(don't forget to incorporate margins, if the element has them. Just add them to the `x` value)

[Here is more on CSS (3d) transforms](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/)

Comment: This did the trick, now I just need to know how to update translate3D on the fly in a .on('move' function

Comment: Try `$("#element").on("move", function(){
 $(this).addClass('move_to_the_left')
});`, and specify that class in your CSS, giving it the correct translate3d values.

Comment: The idea was to make the page snap to finger, so I could move the page, and on 'moveend' I would .addClass('move_to_the_left'). I was looking through some $(element).webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + deltaX + 'px,0px,0px)'; But I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: See this link, I think it will help you out: http://cleanwebdevelopment.com/coding/touch-and-drag-on-the-ipad-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried this technique already, but I couldn't get it to work. I'll try and debug my code to figure out why it won't apply the transform.

Comment: Got it working eventually, however, the swipe using the translate3d triggered by swipe motions works fine, and is fairly smooth. But when I make the slide snap to finger, by using the link above, it gets way too sluggish with the complicated DOM.

Comment: Non-native snap to finger action is slow. I'm afraid it is just something we have to live with for now..